# Buttons for showing/hiding divs not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new on here aswell as new to HTML, CSS and JS.I want to create a button that makes one  visible while at the same time making four other 's invisible. I've tried

```
function ShowGraphics() {

element = document.querySelector("#Graphics");
element.style.visibility = "visible";

element = document.querySelector("#Photos");
element.style.visibility = "hidden";

element = document.querySelector("#Renders");
element.style.visibility = "hidden";

element = document.querySelector("#Videos");
element.style.visibility = "hidden";

element = document.querySelector("#Mods");
element.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

before - including its' variations for each button- , but nothing happened. I've also tried giving each "element" a unique name, made no difference. Maybe one of you could help me out there. Thx in Advance :)

Comment: perhaps you should show some html-markup and where you call your function and so on.

Comment: Hello, i gave you two kinds of solutions, choose between them what you think it would be better for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below

```js
function ShowGraphics() {

element = document.querySelector("#Graphics");
element.style.display= "block";

element = document.querySelector("#Photos");
element.style.display = "none";

element = document.querySelector("#Renders");
element.style.display = "none";

element = document.querySelector("#Videos");
element.style.display = "none";


element = document.querySelector("#Mods");
element.style.display = "none";

}
```

```html
<div id="Graphics">
Hello
</div>

<div id="Photos">
Hello
</div>

<div id="Renders">
Hello
</div>

<div id="Videos">
Hello
</div>

<div id="Mods">
Hello
</div>

<button onclick="ShowGraphics()">Click</button>
```

And if you dont to change the position of button this is your solution :

```js
function ShowGraphics() {
document.getElementById("Graphics").style.visibility = "visible";

document.getElementById("Photos").style.visibility = "hidden";

document.getElementById("Renders").style.visibility = "hidden";

document.getElementById("Videos").style.visibility = "hidden";

document.getElementById("Mods").style.visibility = "hidden";


}
```

```html
<div id="Graphics">
Hello
</div>
<div id="Photos">
Hello
</div>
<div id="Renders">
Hello
</div>
<div id="Videos">
Hello
</div>
<div id="Mods">
Hello
</div>
<button onclick="ShowGraphics()">
Click
</button>
```

Comment: I realized that mine actually worked just as well. Just made a minor mistake in HTML :) But still thx a lot for your help

Comment: I had my doubts if it was normal your code not be working but yes i decided to give you some ways that you could do that easily